# Type Definition file for Keycloak.js

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak auth mechanism for my angular/node/typescript application .I could not find a definitelyTyped d.ts file for Keycloak.js

Is there a typescript equivalent/work in progress for this JBOSS Keycloak.js adapter or do I have to write one ? any inputs/pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: If you can't find it at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) or alongside the project itself then chances are you'll have to write your own definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple one `keycloak.d.ts` can be written with the contents:

```
declare var keycloak:any;
declare module "keycloak" {
    export = keycloak;
}
```

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: Thank you .  +1 for more info :)

Answer (score 14):

<strike>There is an official type definition at:</strike>

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/js/src/main/resources/keycloak.d.ts and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/keycloak-js

**Update:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-js

From @types/keycloak-js:

> keycloak-js provides its own type definitions, so you don't need
> @types/keycloak-js installed!